# resizing javafx shapes positions without scaling them

Tags: java, javafx, geometry, javafx-8

i wan't to create effect similar to that of photoshop when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> that produces frame around the object and resize but i want to just change the position of the contained object not scaling them what i created  so far does the job but the movement is exagerrated and i can't figure out what is wrong with my codehere i am just trying with the northwest handler
thanks in advance
here is images illustrating exactly what i want
the first image is original group with blue circles are controllers
[image]
the second is the group after resizing the group by dragging the north west 
but the components gets scaled also
[image]
the third one is exactly what i want to achieve only change positions without changing the scale 
[image]

```
//this creates the bounding box

public static void cr_resizer(Group root,double x,double y,double X,double Y) {
    Rectangle major=new Rectangle(x-10,y-10,X-x+20,Y-y+20);
    major.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    major.setId("major");
    major.setStrokeWidth(3);
    major.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    major.setDisable(true);
    Circle NW=new Circle(x-10,y-10,3);
    Circle N=new Circle(((x+X)/2),y-10,3);
    Circle NE=new Circle(X+10,y-10,3);
    Circle W=new Circle(x-10,(Y+y)/2,3);
    Circle E=new Circle(X+10,(Y+y)/2,3);
    Circle SE=new Circle(X+10,Y+10,3);
    Circle S=new Circle(((x+X)/2),Y+10,3);
    Circle SW=new Circle(x-10,Y+10,3);
    resize_move( root,NW,SE);
    root.getChildren().addAll(major,NW,N,NE,SE,S,SW,E,W);

}
//this function calculates the calculate the distance of the mover point from the opposing point 
// to caclulate the scaling factor theen apply it to componnents of the group
public static void resize_move(Group root,Circle mover,Circle op) {
    double[]start={mover.getCenterX(),mover.getCenterY()};
    double[]end={op.getCenterX(),op.getCenterY()};
    double[]strt_length=dis2_vec_d(start, end);
    mover.setOnMouseClicked(ev->{
        difx=ev.getX();
        dify=ev.getY();
    });
    mover.setOnMouseDragged(ev->{
        double diffx=ev.getX()-difx;
        double diffy=ev.getY()-dify;
        System.out.println(diffx);
        System.out.println(diffy);
        difx=ev.getX();
        dify=ev.getY();
        mover.setCenterX(ev.getX());
        mover.setCenterY(ev.getY());
        double[] newp= {mover.getCenterX(),mover.getCenterY()};
        double[]end_length=dis2_vec_d(newp, end);
        double[]factor = {end_length[0]/strt_length[0],end_length[1]/strt_length[1]};
        for (Node nod:root.getChildren()) {
            if (nod instanceof Circle) {
                if (nod != mover) {
                    move_circ((Circle) nod,op,factor);
                }

            }
        }
    });

}
//this function relocate the position of the circle according to the position of the custom axis point
public static void move_circ(Circle cir,Circle op,double[]factor) {
double[] axis= {op.getCenterX(),op.getCenterY()};
double[] strt_point= {cir.getCenterX(),cir.getCenterY()};
double[] nstrt_point= new_cord(axis,strt_point,factor);
cir.setCenterX(nstrt_point[0]);
cir.setCenterY(nstrt_point[1]);

}
//this function scale the position of the point in relation to another point
public static double[] new_cord(double[]axis,double[]point,double[]factor) {
double[]strt_length=dis2_vec_d(point,axis);
double[]new_length= {strt_length[0]*factor[0],strt_length[1]*factor[1]};
double[]new_point= {new_length[0]+axis[0],new_length[1]+axis[1]};
return new_point;
}
//this function calculates the distance
public static double[] dis2_vec_d(double[]p1,double[]p2) {
double[] vec = new double[2];
vec[0]=p1[0]-p2[0];
vec[1]=p1[1]-p2[1];
return vec;
}
```

Comment: I assume there are the coders who are willing to read all of your code. But, I think you should reduce it with **minimal** portion of code and allow rest of us to try to help you.

Comment: @zlakad i tried to comment every function as i can't reduce it as i told i don't know which part is missing with my results

Comment: are you trying to move the object or resize (aka scale)?

Comment: @JoseMartinez i have updated the question with images to illustrate exactly what i want to achieve

Comment: @zlakad  i have updated the question with images to illustrate exactly what i want to achieve –

Comment: You're almost there. Why don't you just repaint the objects at the end of dragging mouse with theirs original sizes?

Comment: @zlakad do you mean deleting the old ones and create new ones 
but the problem that my code exaggerate the amount of dragging and i don't know what is wrong with my code

Comment: Again, I didn't read your code - what is the container for your objects? See the properties of that container... Good luck, friend.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to make your Node draggable.  I created a class that does this, pasted below.

You might have to replace a few instances of a class called GameScreen in my code below.

```
public class Draggable {

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //variables
    AtomicBoolean myPressed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Point2D myInitialTranslates;
    Point2D dragInitialTranslates;
    EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> onMouseReleased;
    EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> onMousePressed;
    EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> onMouseDragged;
    OnDrag onDrag;
    boolean stayWithinBounds = true;
    double minX = 0;
    double maxX = WIDTH;
    double minY = 0;
    double maxY = GameScreen.PLAY_AREA_HEIGHT;
    boolean doNotTranslate = false;
    //handleX and handleY are offsets used strictly for the callbacks, they are not used for the translation of the destination Node.
    double handleX = 0;
    double handleY = 0;
    double X;
    double Y;
    boolean reverseX = false;
    boolean reverseY = false;
    float amountOfTargetNodeToAllowOutsideLimit = 0f;

    public void setOnDrag(OnDrag onDrag) {
        this.onDrag = onDrag;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //constructors
    public Draggable() {
    }

    public Draggable(double handleX, double handleY) {
        this.handleX = handleX;
        this.handleY = handleY;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //methods
    public void makeDraggable(Node source, Node target, double dragAdjustmentRatioX, double dragAdjustmentRatioY) {
        source.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
            if (myPressed.get() && !doNotTranslate) {
                double x = myInitialTranslates.getX() - dragInitialTranslates.getX() + dragAdjustmentRatioX * GameScreen.instance.scaleXToScreen(event.getSceneX());
                double y = myInitialTranslates.getY() - dragInitialTranslates.getY() + dragAdjustmentRatioY * GameScreen.instance.scaleYToScreen(event.getSceneY());
                double localMaxX = maxX - target.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() * amountOfTargetNodeToAllowOutsideLimit;
                double localMinX = minX - target.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() * amountOfTargetNodeToAllowOutsideLimit;
                if (x > localMinX && x < localMaxX) {
                    target.setTranslateX(x);
                } else {
//                    Log.debug("X is not within range.  x = " + x);
                }
                double localMaxY = maxY - target.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() * amountOfTargetNodeToAllowOutsideLimit;
                double localMinY = minY - target.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() * amountOfTargetNodeToAllowOutsideLimit;
                if (y > localMinY && y < localMaxY) {
                    target.setTranslateY(y);
                } else {
//                    Log.debug("Y is not within range.  x = " + y);
                }
            } else {
            }
            if (onMouseDragged != null) {
                onMouseDragged.handle(event);
            }
            if (onDrag != null) {
                if (reverseX) {
                    X = handleX + dragInitialTranslates.getX() - dragAdjustmentRatioX * GameScreen.instance.scaleXToScreen(event.getSceneX());
                } else {
                    X = handleX - dragInitialTranslates.getX() + dragAdjustmentRatioX * GameScreen.instance.scaleXToScreen(event.getSceneX());
                }
                if (reverseY) {
                    Y = handleY + dragInitialTranslates.getY() - dragAdjustmentRatioY * GameScreen.instance.scaleYToScreen(event.getSceneY());
                } else {
                    Y = handleY - dragInitialTranslates.getY() + dragAdjustmentRatioY * GameScreen.instance.scaleYToScreen(event.getSceneY());
                }
                onDrag.handle(X, Y);
            }
        });
        source.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
            myInitialTranslates = new Point2D(target.getTranslateX(), target.getTranslateY());
            dragInitialTranslates = new Point2D(
                    dragAdjustmentRatioX * GameScreen.instance.scaleXToScreen(event.getSceneX()),
                    dragAdjustmentRatioY * GameScreen.instance.scaleYToScreen(event.getSceneY()));
            myPressed.set(true);
            if (onMousePressed != null) {
                onMousePressed.handle(event);
            }
            GameScreen.setCursorMove();
        });
        source.setOnMouseReleased((MouseEvent event) -> {
            myPressed.set(false);
            handleX = X;
            handleY = Y;
            if (onMouseReleased != null) {
                onMouseReleased.handle(event);
            }
            GameScreen.setCursorCustom();
        });
    }

    public void makeDraggable(Node node, double dragAdjustmentRatioX, double dragAdjustmentRatioY) {
        makeDraggable(node, node, dragAdjustmentRatioX, dragAdjustmentRatioY);
    }

    public void setOnMouseReleased(EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> onMouseReleased) {
        this.onMouseReleased = onMouseReleased;
    }

    public void setOnMousePressed(EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> onMousePressed) {
        this.onMousePressed = onMousePressed;
    }

    public void setOnMouseDragged(EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> onMouseDragged) {
        this.onMouseDragged = onMouseDragged;
    }

    public void setAmountOfTargetNodeToAllowOutsideLimit(float amountOfTargetNodeToAllowOutsideLimit) {
        this.amountOfTargetNodeToAllowOutsideLimit = amountOfTargetNodeToAllowOutsideLimit;
    }

    public interface OnDrag {

        public void handle(double x, double y);
    }

    public boolean isStayWithinBounds() {
        return stayWithinBounds;
    }

    public void setStayWithinBounds(boolean stayWithinBounds) {
        this.stayWithinBounds = stayWithinBounds;
    }

    public void setMinMax(double minX, double maxX, double minY, double maxY) {
        this.maxX = maxX;
        this.minX = minX;
        this.minY = minY;
        this.maxY = maxY;
    }

    public void setDoNotTranslate(boolean doNotTranslate) {
        this.doNotTranslate = doNotTranslate;
    }

    public boolean isReverseX() {
        return reverseX;
    }

    public void setReverseX(boolean reverseX) {
        this.reverseX = reverseX;
    }

    public boolean isReverseY() {
        return reverseY;
    }

    public void setReverseY(boolean reverseY) {
        this.reverseY = reverseY;
    }

    public double getHandleX() {
        return handleX;
    }

    public void setHandleX(double handleX) {
        this.handleX = handleX;
    }

    public double getHandleY() {
        return handleY;
    }

    public void setHandleY(double handleY) {
        this.handleY = handleY;
    }

}
```

`GameScreen.instance.scaleXToScreen` and `GameScreen.instance.scaleYToScreen` just set this to 1.  In the future if you scale your window, you might need to adjust for it.

`GameScreen.WIDTH` and `GameScreen.PLAY_HEIGHT` set tot he width and height of your scene.

The two method calls to change the mouse cursor can be deleted.

The way you use it is like this...

```
new Draggable().makeDraggable(nodeYouWantToDrag, 1, 1);
```

and thats that.

EDIT:  it also has callbacks for basic events like onDrag, onMousePressed, onMouseDragged, and onMouseReleased.